# Command not executing after installation Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-18.04

- I'm using ubuntu 18.04 machine. I'm facing some issues from last few days. After installing some programs, commands aren't executing. Before some days, i had installed `nodemon` with `npm`. After installation i just execute `nodemon` and it says `Command 'nodemon' not found, did you mean..`. I tried restarting terminal and them my machine. Tried installing it globally and with `sudo` too.
- It happened again with me just now. With commands `ngx` and `firebase`.

What to do with this. Please comment if you need additional info.

Answer (score 1):

Finally find the solution. It was npm issues. i won't giving me any error but just won't working says `command not found`. So it fixed by reconfiguring npm directory. Here is ref. https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally